# Access columns of an R data.table as a matrix, by reference

Tags: r, matrix, reference, data.table

I recall there is a special (undocumented?) form that allows accessing selected columns of a data.table by reference as a matrix (in so doing allocating no memory) but for the life of me I can't find my note on the subject.  Something analogous to setDF, but yielding a matrix, not a data.frame.  I understand this might come with certain dangers, and would like to be reminded of how to do this, and what the dangers are.

Comment: Not clear what you're after. `as.matrix` will convert your table to a matrix. `DT[1:5, 6:7]` will return the first 5 rows of columns 6/7

Comment: it is not possible, because matrix has different layout in memory than list/data.frame/data.table, and we don't have any mapping that allows that.

Comment: thanks @jangorecki - your explanation is cogent.  My recollection must be incorrect.

Comment: @malcook I made my comment an answer, because I don't like to leave an unanswered questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, because matrix has different layout in memory than list/data.frame/data.table, and we don't have any mapping that allows that.